# Why does AWS Schema Conversion Tool use the JAR format for for MS SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, jdbc, aws-sct

During a demo in a recent AWS webinar, a JAR file was specified as a driver for the Schema Conversion Tool to connect to an MS SQL Server db (I am providing a screenshot from the webinar).  Why was JDBC chosen?  Was this optional, and was a choice made by the person who presented the webinar?  If so, what other options would be available as a driver?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Schema Conversion Tool [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/SchemaConversionTool/latest/userguide/CHAP_Installing.html#CHAP_Installing.JDBCDrivers):

> For the AWS SCT to work correctly, you must install the JDBC drivers
>   for your source and target database engines.

Comment: Yes I saw that link, but are you certain that JDBC is the only option? Thank you.

Comment: As per AWS doc, yes.

Comment: The tool is (supposedly) written in Java, hence the need of  JDBC drivers